# Comparing versions in xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code to compare current and available version:

```
NSString *currentVersion = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *avaliableVersionData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                  @"http://update.blockade.tech/current-version"] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *avaliableVersion = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:avaliableVersionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([avaliableVersion compare:currentVersion options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"lower");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
```

But when those versions are same(0.1.2 and 0.1.2), it write than current version is lower. Why is it?

Comment: Make sure there is no extra white space or new line in the availableVersion.

Comment: There is no extra space

Comment: You should also account for a `NULL` value being returned.

Comment: So it seems there was extra white space after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web result contains a newline.  Strip out the newline after the `initWithData:...` call and before the `if` statement with:

```
avaliableVersion = [avaliableVersion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```